# Firebase Social Login Issue with Ionic

Tags: firebase, authentication, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I have an app in Ionic 1 and Firebase 3.

I'm able to login using Facebook without trouble. This has no issues as long as I log out and try logging in again.

The login feature doesn't work, if I close the app without Signing Out, and try logging in again.

Is there any way that I could enforce a session logout when the app closes?

Comment: You want to automatically sign out each time the app is closed? Is this a mobile app?

Comment: Yes this is a mobile app written in ionic.

Comment: You can trigger signout when "pause" event triggers: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/cordova/events/events.html#pause